# Tsconfig and outDir issue

Tags: typescript, tsconfig

I am having issue with my outDir in tsconfig.json.

I have the following tsconfig file:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "removeComments": false,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "outDir": "dist",
    "outFile": "App.js"
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "local_typings"
  ]
}
```

The files are compiled to App.js, however not in the directory I've specified (dist), but in the directory, where tsconfig file is. Anyone has found solution to this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, I found out what was the issue. I think its pretty funny: its enough to specify file path and file name in the `outFile`, without using `outDir`. So, in this case, this would be:

```
"outFile":"dist/App.js"
```

Have a good one!

Comment: And if you have 50 `.ts` files?

Comment: outFile will consolidate all the ts files into one

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, TypeScript (at least as of version 3.3) does not support both `outDir` and `outFile` simultaneously.

I too would like to keep my source directory clean of intermediate build files while still using TypeScript to bundle my code into a single file rather than needing to shell out to a 3rd party utility such as webpack, parcel, or rollup to then combine all its output into a single file, but alas, that is (currently) not to be.

(However to simply generate the bundled output in a different directory, yes, `outFile: "subdir/bundle.js"` will work just fine.)

Answer (score 0):

To a file or many use "outDir":"./dist"

Answer (score 0):

### To anyone looking for a way to import from module rather than module/dist/Anything

I found an rather easy solution

First thing, my folder structure looks something like this

```
- project
|- package.json

|- app
||- package.json
||- ...

|- api
||- package.json
||- ...

|- shared
||- package.json
||- tsconfig.json
||- index.ts
||- src
|||- MySharedResource.ts
|||- MySharedSomething.ts
...
```

(shared is an npm package installed locally in both api and app)
And I wanted to be able to import things from shared using simple
`import { MySharedResource } from "shared";`

The way to do this was to export every needed component from `MySharedResource.ts` and `MySharedSomething.ts`

```
export interface MySharedResource {
 ...
}
```

and then export it from `index.ts` like this:

```
export * from "./src/MySharedResource";
export * from "./src/MySharedSomething";
```

#### Important note

Your `tsconfig.json` in /shared should have **outDir** option set to `./dist` (for example), so that `index.ts` gets compiled to `/shared/dist/index.js` and all the other stuff gets compiled into /shared/dist/src.
Also, in your `package.json` set:

```
"main":"dist/index.js"
```

#### Note 1

You can have multiple things per file exported, but if you want to have imports like this one

```
import { Thing } from 'shared/Thing';
```

Then you need to have another file (in this case `Thing.ts`) right next to `index.ts` in /shared with the following in it:

```
export * from "./src/Task";
```

#### Note 2

You can also do this

```
export * as Thing from "./src/Thing";
```